# How to Optimized performance of JOIN query on large table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am using Server version: 5.5.28-log MySQL Community Server (GPL).

I have a big table consist of 279703655 records called table A. I have to perform join on this table with one of my changelog table B and then insert matching records in new tmp table C.

B table has index on column type.

A table consist of prod_id,his_id and other columns.A table has index on both column prod_id,history_id.

When i am going to perform the following query

```
INSERT INTO C(prod,his_id,comm) 
SELECT DISTINCT a.product_id,a.history_id,comm
        FROM B as b INNER JOIN A as a ON a.his_id = b.his_id AND b.type="applications"
        GROUP BY prod_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `his_id` = VALUES(`his_id`);
```

it takes 7 to 8 min to insert records.

Even if i perform simple count from table A it took 15 min to give me count.

I have also tried a procedure to insert records in Limit but due to count query takes 15 min it is more slower then before.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A INTO n;
SET i=5000000;
WHILE i<n DO 
 INSERT INTO C(product_id,history_id,comments) 
        SELECT a.product_id,a.history_id,a.comments FROM B as b 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM A LIMIT i,1) as a ON a.history_id=b.history_id;
  SET i = i + 5000000;
END WHILE;
End
```

But the above code is also take 15 to 20 min o execute.

Please suggest me how i make it faster.

Below is `EXPLAIN` result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |       ref       |     rows     |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL    | (NULL)        | (NULL)  | (NULL)  | (NULL)          |    279703655 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | DB.a.history_id |            1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

(from Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE B (
    history_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    history_hash char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    type enum('products','brands','partnames','mc_partnames','applications') NOT NULL, 
    stamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (history_id), 
    UNIQUE KEY history_hash (history_hash), 
    KEY type (type), 
    KEY stamp (stamp)
);
```

Comment: `GROUP BY prod_id` does not make sense given the other columns you are selecting.  You might want to add sample data which demonstrates what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN` result on your query too, thanks

Comment: I am selecting product_id as well in above query.
Here is Explain result of above query.

id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE a ALL     279703655 
1 SIMPLE b eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 DB.a.history_id 1 Using index

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Actually I have changelog table in which i have last 7 days changed add/edit/updated records which in above case table B.

Table A has all the app history records.

I have to get only those app records which have been changed last 7 days.

Comment: Changed last 7 days? Yet there's no criteria on a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME used? I'd expect that at least a changelog table should have such column.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  How big is B?

Comment: @LukStorms Yes you are right i have TIMESTAMP  in my table B. I am getting records of last 7 days in my table B from other table.

Comment: I'm guessing tableA doesn't have a [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html) setup.

Comment: @LukStorms Yes A does not have any partitioning setup because it is very old table and at that time it does not have that much of records.

Comment: What is  table A's primary key? And table C is new? Empty? Why `ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` then? Is `prod_id` = `product_id` or are these different columns? Is `his_id` = `history_id` or are these different columns?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Apologies for my bad.Yes his_id = history_id and prod_id = product_id.Table A primary key is product_id. ON Duplicate key update is for because in previous step i am inserting some records for my product history so it may be the case that it may conflict with product id of my applications.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes needed (assuming it is `history_id`, not `his_id`):

```
B:  INDEX(type, history_id) -- in this order.  Note: "covering"
A:  INDEX(history_id, product_id, comm)
```

What column or combination of columns provides the uniqueness constraint that IODKU needs?

Really-- Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `history_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `history_hash` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('products','brands','partnames','mc_partnames','applications') NOT NULL,
  `stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `history_hash` (`history_hash`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `stamp` (`stamp`)
);

Comment: Are `his_id` and `history_id` the same?  How about `SHOW CREATE TABLE C`

Comment: Apologies for my bad.Yes his_id = history_id and prod_id = product_id.Table C is creating from above select....query.

Comment: @RupeshRanjangaonkar - Updated

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at the tables.

- What you call table B is really a history table. Its primary key is the `history_id`.
- What you call table A is really a product table with one product per row and `product_id` its primary key. Each product also has a `history_id`. Thus you have created a 1:n relation. A product has one history row; one history row relates to multiple products.

You are selecting the product table rows that have an 'application' type history entry. This should be written as:

```
select product_id, history_id, comm
from product
where history_id in 
(
  select history_id
  from history 
  where type = 'applications'
);
```

(A join would work just as well, but isn't as clear. As there is only one history row per product, you can't get duplicates. Both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` are completely superfluous in your query and should be removed in order not to give the DBMS unecessary work to do. But as mentioned: better don't join at all. If you want rows from table A, select from table A. If you want to look up rows in table B, look them up in the `WHERE` clause, where all criteria belongs.)

Now, we would have to know how many rows may be affected. If only 1% of all history rows are 'applications', then an index should be used. Preferably

```
create index idx1 on history (type, history_id);
```

… which finds rows by `type` and gets their `history_id` right away.

If, say 20%, of all all history rows are 'applications', then reading the table sequentially might be more efficient.

Then, how many product rows may we get? Even with a single history row, we might get millions of related product rows. Or vice versa, with millions of history rows we might get no product row at all. Again, we can provide an index, which may or may not be used by the DBMS:

```
create index idx2 on product (history_id, product_id, comm);
```

This is about as fast as it gets. Two indexes offered and a proper written query without an unnecessary join. There were times when MySQL had performance problems with `IN`. People rewrote the clause with `EXISTS` then. I don't think this is still necessary.

As of MySQL 8.0.3, you can create histogram statistics for tables.

```
analyze history update histogram on type;
analyze product update histogram on history_id;
```

This is an important step to help the optimizer to find the optimal way to select the data.